# make can't find sys/signal.h

Tags: c, makefile, mingw, configure, m4

I’m trying to install `m4` in MINGW

After `./configure` ended normally I tried `make` but error was occurred.

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/src/autotools/build_m4/src'
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I../../m4-1.4/src -I../../m4-1.4/src/../lib  -g -O
../../m4-1.4/src/m4.c
../../m4-1.4/src/m4.c:22:24: fatal error: sys/signal.h: No such file or director
y
 #include <sys/signal.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [m4.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/src/autotools/build_m4/src'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

`signal.h` is in `\c\mingw\include` that is set in PATH environment.

How can I tell `make` where `signal.h` is?

Comment: On most Unix systems, the file `/usr/include/signal.h` contains `#include <sys/signal.h>`. It seems that `m4` is assuming that there will be a `<sys/signal.h>` — presumably without having `autoconf` check that it exists. This could be a bug in `m4`, or it could be a problem with your setup. Have you been able to compile programs before? Is there a directory `/c/mingw/include/sys` (or the backslash equivalent)? If not, you may be able to get going by creating a `sys` subdirectory (if it is missing) and copying `signal.h` into it. But it is a hack workaround for a probable bug.

Comment: `make` doesn't care for this include file. Its the compiler. Pass the appropriate pass to GCC.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Neither mingw not \any\path\with\backslahes isn't Linux.

Comment: Yes, @harper, I know that MinGW is Minimal GNU for Windows.  It is intended, I believe, to provide an environment in which programs that originate on Unix can be compiled and run.  It is not an exact replica of Unix or Linux, but it is, I believe, meant to make it relatively easy to port code from Unix or Linux to Windows if it is autoconfigured appropriately.  To build `m4`, you are expected to use the `configure` shell script which autoconfigures.  It should detect MinGW and respond appropriately.  Alternatively, use Cygwin instead; that certainly works remarkably well as a Unix surrogate.

Comment: As @Jonathan Leffler said,I copied `signal.h` into `sys`.Then `make` run and finished normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a comment into an answer:

> On most Unix systems, the file `/usr/include/signal.h` contains `#include <sys/signal.h>`. It seems that `m4` is assuming that there will be a `<sys/signal.h>` — presumably without having `autoconf` check that it exists. This could be a bug in (the configuration process for) `m4`, or it could be a problem with your setup.
>
> Have you been able to compile other GNU programs before? Is there a directory `/c/mingw/include/sys` (or `\c\mingw\include\sys`)? If not, you may be able to get going by creating a `sys` subdirectory in `\c\mingw\include` (if it is missing) and copying `signal.h` into it. But it is a hack workaround for a probable bug.

If this works — as it seems to — check whether your MinGW installation was correct and up to date.  If so, report the problem to the maintainers of [`m4`](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) (email `bug-m4` at `gnu.org`), but check the web site for instructions on how to do that.

Consider removing the copied `signal.h` as it wasn't there originally.  OTOH, you may need it again in the future — but personally, I'd feel happier if the installation were in its pristine state normally and the hack was only made when absolutely necessary.

Comment: On mine `<sys/signal.h>` contains `#include <signal.h>`. So it can go both ways, but in all cases there is one real include and one that includes the other.